# Running stopwatch timer in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, timer

I have found a couple of answers for this question, but they are not very helpful. I am trying to create an app that has a running stopwatch timer in each cell of a tableview, using standard subtitle cells. The timer name is displayed in the textfield and the running timer is displayed in the subtitle. Each cell needs to display a different time format (seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, or years). The calculation of the time elapsed since the timer was started is done each time the timer expires, and the result is put into the cell's subtitle. The code works fine as long as only one timer is used. However, if a second timer is started, the running timer in the first cell is reset to zero. I believe this is because I am saving a pointer to the cell dequeued at cellForRowAtIndexPath: and using this pointer to populate the cell when the timer expires. This probably violates MVC. However, as my view controller delegate implements the protocol, I have to return a cell when the tableview requests it, and I can't do that until the timer expires so that I can update the subtitle in the cell. I don't see any way to do this without saving a pointer to the cell containing the output of the running timer. I am new to iOS development but I have written this project both programmatically and recently using a storyboard and get the same results. The code for the view controller is below. Note that the item.timerType is set from another view controller that is segued in the storyboard with the data passed back to the main view controller. That part works ok.

Thanks for any help!

```
    //
//  timerItem.h
//  LifeLogger
//
//  Created by Nelson Capes on 9/24/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Nelson Capes. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface timerItem : NSObject

@property NSString *timerName;
@property NSTimeInterval interval;
@property NSString *timerOutput;
@property NSDate *startTime;
@property NSTimer *timer;
@property NSInteger timerType;
@property UITableViewCell *cell;
@end

    //
//  NRCTimerListTableViewController.h
//  LifeLogger
//
//  Created by Nelson Capes on 9/21/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Nelson Capes. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AddTimerItemViewController.h"
@interface NRCTimerListTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
-(IBAction)listToAdd:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@property NSTimer *timer;
@property(strong) timerItem *item;
@property NSDate *startTime;



@end

    //
//  NRCTimerListTableViewController.m
//  LifeLogger
//
//  Created by Nelson Capes on 9/21/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Nelson Capes. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NRCTimerListTableViewController.h"
#import "timerItem.h"
@interface NRCTimerListTableViewController ()


@property NSMutableArray *items;


@end

@implementation NRCTimerListTableViewController

// control comes here when user hits the Save button in AddTimerItemViewController.
// 
-(IBAction)listToAdd:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{
    if(!self.items){
        self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];}
    if(self.item != nil)
    {
    [self.items addObject:self.item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
-(void)loadInitialData{
    // get a timerItem object to pass onto to subsequent view controllers

    // and add it to items array

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadInitialData];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.items count];;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    // First, get a pointer to the timer item from the items array


    switch (self.item.timerType) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSTimeInterval interval = 1;
            self.item.interval = interval;
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            NSTimeInterval interval = 60;
            self.item.interval = interval;
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            NSTimeInterval interval = 3600;
            self.item.interval = interval;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            NSTimeInterval interval = (3600 * 24);
            self.item.interval = interval;
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            NSTimeInterval interval = (36600 * 24 * 30);
            self.item.interval = interval;
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            NSTimeInterval interval = (3600 * 24 * 365);
            self.item.interval = interval;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }


        self.item.cell = cell;

      //  cell.textLabel.text = self.item.timerName;

        // set the start time in the item
        self.item.startTime = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval startInterval = self.item.interval;
        self.item.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:startInterval target:self selector:@selector(timerCount:) userInfo:self.item repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.item.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

        // debug ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        NSLog(@"Item %@ timer started", self.item.timerName);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        [self.item.timer fire];

    // set the textLabel in the cell to the itemName
        return cell;
}

-(void)timerCount:t
    {

        NSTimer *timer = t;
        timerItem *item = timer.userInfo;
        NSLog(@"Item %@ timer fired", item.timerName);
        NSTimeInterval endInterval = [item.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
        endInterval = (-1 * endInterval);

        switch (item.timerType) {
            case 0:
            {
                int time = round(endInterval);
                div_t h = div(time, 3600); //seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                int hours = h.quot;         // hours, divided by 60 equals
                div_t m = div(h.rem, 60);   // minutes
                int minutes = m.quot;
                int seconds = m.rem;        // and remainder is seconds
                NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds", hours, minutes, seconds];

                NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                item.timerOutput = outputString;

            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                int time = round(endInterval);
                div_t h = div(time, 3600);      // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                int hours = h.quot;             // hours, divided by 60 equals
                div_t m = div(h.rem, 60);       // minutes
                int minutes = m.quot;
                NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours, %d minutes", hours, minutes];
                NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                item.timerOutput = outputString;
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                int time = round(endInterval);
                div_t h = div(time, 3600); // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                int hours = h.quot;        // hours
                NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours", hours];
                NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                item.timerOutput = outputString;
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                int time = round(endInterval);

                div_t h = div(time, 3600); // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                int hours = h.quot;        // hours, divided by 24 equals
                div_t d =div(h.rem, 24);   // days
                int days = d.quot;
                NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days, %d hours", days, hours];
                NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                item.timerOutput = outputString;
            }
                break;
            case 4:
            {
                int time = round(endInterval);
                div_t h = div(time, 3600); // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                __unused int hours = h.quot;        // hours, divided by 24 equals
                div_t d =div(h.rem, 24);   // days
                int days = d.quot;
                div_t y = div(d.rem, 12);// divided by 12 equals months
                int months = y.quot;
                NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d months, %d days", months, days];
                NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                item.timerOutput = outputString;
            }
                break;
            case 5:
            {
                int time = round(endInterval);
                div_t h = div(time, 3600); // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                __unused int hours = h.quot;        // hours, divided by 24 equals
                div_t d =div(h.rem, 24);   // days
                int days = d.quot;
                div_t y = div(d.rem, 365);// divided by 365 equals years
                int years = y.quot;
                NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d years, %d days", years, days];
                NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                item.timerOutput = outputString;
            }
                break;
        }
        item.cell.textLabel.text = item.timerName;
        item.cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.timerOutput;

    }




/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"listToAdd"]){
        self.item = [[timerItem alloc]init];
        AddTimerItemViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.timerItem = self.item;}
}
/*
#pragma mark - Table view delegate
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


}
 */
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

My code like this works until you scroll the tableView after the maximum number of cells that can fit on a screen have been filled. For example, on an iPhone 6 and a cell height of 60, I can fit about 11 rows on the screen. All of the timers in my rows are fine up to that point. But, if I scroll back to see the first cells, unpredictable things happen - some of the cells have their timers reset. This is only really noticeable if the timers are set to one second. At a longer interval (say, a minute), it isn't much of a problem but I suspect the hole is still there.  This is the code I am using:

```
    -(void) calculateTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer

{
    self.timerItem = [theTimer userInfo];


        // for date only cell
        if(self.timerItem.timerType == 0){
            [theTimer invalidate];
        }

        // if this cell is visible and is the one for which the name and type were set, put the name into the cell
        for(NRCItemCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells])
        {
            //NSLog(@"cell = %@", cell);

            NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            NSUInteger row = [[[NRCItemStore sharedStore]allItems] indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:self.timerItem];

            NSLog(@"ip = %@, row = %lu", ip, (unsigned long)row);

            if (row == ip.row){
                cell.timerName.text = self.timerItem.timerName;

                // timerType set by TimerTypeTableView Controller as follows:

                // 0 - date
                // 1 - seconds elapsed
                // 2 - minutes elapsed
                // 3 - hours elapsed
                // 4 - days elapsed
                // 5 - months elapsed
                // 6 - years elapsed

                switch (self.timerItem.timerType) {
                    case 0:{
                        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
                        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

                        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
                        NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
                        cell.timer.text = formattedDateString;
                    }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                    {
                        NSTimeInterval interval = [self.timerItem.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
                        interval = (-1 * interval);
                        int time = round(interval);
                        div_t h = div(time, 3600); //seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                        int hours = h.quot;         // hours, divided by 60 equals
                        div_t m = div(h.rem, 60);   // minutes
                        int minutes = m.quot;
                        int seconds = m.rem;        // and remainder is seconds
                        //  NSLog(@"%d:%d:%d", hours, minutes, seconds);
                        //NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)time];
                        NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds", hours, minutes, seconds];

                        NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                        cell.timer.text = outputString;

                    }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                    {
                        NSTimeInterval interval = [self.timerItem.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
                        interval = (-1 * interval);
                        int time = roundf(interval);
                        div_t h = div(time, 3600);      // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                        int hours = h.quot;             // hours, divided by 60 equals
                        div_t m = div(h.rem, 60);       // minutes
                        int minutes = m.quot;
                        NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours, %d minutes", hours, minutes];
                        NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];

                        cell.timer.text = outputString;

                    }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                    {
                        NSTimeInterval interval = [self.timerItem.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
                        interval = (-1 * interval);
                        int time = roundf(interval);
                        div_t h = div(time, 3600); // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                        int hours = h.quot;        // hours
                        NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours", hours];
                        NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];

                        cell.timer.text = outputString;
                    }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                    {
                        NSTimeInterval interval = [self.timerItem.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
                        interval = (-1 * interval);
                        int time = roundf(interval);
                        div_t h = div(time, 3600); // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                        int hours = h.quot;        // hours, divided by 24 equals
                        div_t d =div(h.rem, 24);   // days
                        int days = d.quot;
                        NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days, %d hours", days, hours];
                        NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];

                        cell.timer.text = outputString;
                    }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                    {
                        NSTimeInterval interval = [self.timerItem.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
                        interval = (-1 * interval);
                        int time = roundf(interval);
                        div_t h = div(time, 3600); // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                        __unused int hours = h.quot;        // hours, divided by 24 equals
                        div_t d =div(h.rem, 24);   // days
                        int days = d.quot;
                        div_t y = div(d.rem, 12);// divided by 12 equals months
                        int months = y.quot;
                        NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d months, %d days", months, days];
                        NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                        cell.timer.text = outputString;
                    }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                    {
                        NSTimeInterval interval = [self.timerItem.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
                        interval = (-1 * interval);
                        int time = roundf(interval);
                        div_t h = div(time, 3600); // seconds total, divided by 3600 equals
                        __unused int hours = h.quot;        // hours, divided by 24 equals
                        div_t d =div(h.rem, 24);   // days
                        int days = d.quot;
                        div_t y = div(d.rem, 365);// divided by 365 equals years
                        int years = y.quot;
                        NSString *intervalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d years, %d days", years, days];
                        NSString *outputString = [intervalString stringByAppendingString:@" ago"];
                        cell.timer.text = outputString;
                    }
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You only really need one timer to do the update (every second, tenth of a seconds or whatever). Then you just keep track of when and if cells have been started. So create an array like self.timestamps with the start time [NSDate date] for every cell, let it be nil or something if not started. You could even let it be a NSString with the latest time as a string if it's stopped, that way you could set this value in cellForItemAtIndexPath: and just skip it in your timer by checking if it's a NSString rather than NSDate.

Then in your timer you use NSArray *visibleCells = [tableView visibleCells] to get the list of the cells currently being shown. Loop through that list getting the UITableViewCells and use IndexPath *ip = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell] that you then can use to get the correct timer for that cell. Then update that cell's view (title, subtitle or whatever).

Something like this in your timer

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
  NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
  id object = [self.timestamps objectForIndex:ip.row];

  if(object && [object isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {

    // It's started
    NSDate timeStampForCell = (NSDate)timeStampForCell;
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:timeStampForCell];
    [cell setDetailTextLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)seconds]];

    } else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){

    // It's stopped

    } else {

    // It's never been started

    }
}
```